# android how to send and receive image and location (using map ) in group chat using xmpp-smack

Tags: android, tcp, connection, xmpp, file-transfer

i developing group chat app using android-xmpp, in that i don't know how to send and recive pics-image or location (using map).

So any one one can please give me way to do these.

currently , i got text message and add to list view , like following ,

```
Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.groupchat);
msg.setBody(text);
if (Constants.connection != null) {
    try {
        Constants.connection.sendPacket(msg);
        Log.d("Send to room  : Name : ", to);
        Log.d("store", "store data to db");
        //DBAdapter.addUserData(new UserData(text, "", "1" ,beam_id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ooo", "msg exception" + e.getMessage());
    }

    messages.add(text);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           // set to listview
            setMyChatAdapter();
        }
    });
}
```

and receive using StanzaTypeFilter. So how for image and location sharing ?

I try following code for image using  FileTransferManager , using **smack-extensions-4.1.3-sources.jar** .

```
 private void sendImage()
 {

  FileTransferManager mg=new FileTransferManager(Constants.connection);
  OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = mg.createOutgoingFileTransfer(beam_id+"@"+Constants.conference_name + "/" + Constants.resources);
  File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
  try {
      transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  while(!transfer.isDone()) {
      if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
          System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
      } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
              || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
          System.out.println("Cancelled!!! "+ transfer.getError());
      }
      try {
          Thread.sleep(1000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
          || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
      System.out.println("refused cancelled error"+ transfer.getError());
   } else {
      System.out.println("Success");
   }
}
```

But when i access that file using following ,

**FileTransferManager mg=new FileTransferManager(Constants.connection);**

it give me error **... has a private access of ...** So , i find constructor of that file is private , this is jar file so i can not change it to public .

So, how can i access that file-class into my class ?

So, how can i share(send-receive) image and location message in chat ?

Please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

try this link: [reference](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-file-transfer-with-asmack-and.html)

**For File send**

```
FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer('usre2@myHost/Smack');
File file = new File(filenameWithPath);
try {
   transfer.sendFile(file, 'test_file');
     } catch (XMPPException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
while(!transfer.isDone()) {
   if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
      System.out.println('ERROR!!! ' + transfer.getError());
   } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled)
                    || transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused)) {
      System.out.println('Cancelled!!! ' + transfer.getError());
   }
   try {
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)
 || transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled)){
   System.out.println('refused cancelled error ' + transfer.getError());
} else {
   System.out.println('Success');
}
```

**File Receive:**

```
FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
   public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
      new Thread(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
            IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
            File mf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(mf.getAbsoluteFile()+'/DCIM/Camera/' + transfer.getFileName());
            try{
                transfer.recieveFile(file);
                while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                   try{
                      Thread.sleep(1000L);
                   }catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.e('', e.getMessage());
                   }
                   if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                      Log.e('ERROR!!! ', transfer.getError() + '');
                   }
                   if(transfer.getException() != null) {
                      transfer.getException().printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
             }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e('', e.getMessage());
            }
         };
       }.start();
    }
 });
```

Comment: hello @kiturk3 i know this code but how to access if **FileTransferManager** have a private access , that i clear mention in my question.

Comment: This interface has changed.  You must now call FileTransferManager.getInstance(Connection)

Comment: my file does not send.
i got System.out.println('refused cancelled error ' + transfer.getError());
Can you tell me what should be the causes

Comment: @Rajat are permissions ok?

Answer (score 1):

The `FileTransferManager` class have `getInstanceFor(XMPPConnection connection)` to get the instance of the `FileTransferManager`. Just provide a valid XMPPConnecton. e.g.

`FileTransferManager ftm = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection)`

See this link [FileTransferManager](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/filetransfer/FileTransferManager.html) too.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: As per the doc link FileTransferManager uses EntityFullJid. Does that mean it will work for sending to room as well?

Comment: @Killer i haven't tried that kind of approach. But it seems this `FileTransferManager` works for 1-to-1 approach. You can try to check this link [Out of Band Data](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html)